# How to use zinc sulfide to produce hydrogen (via photolysis)

Tags: water, home-experiment, catalysis

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_sulfide#Catalyst), zinc sulfide added to water and then brought into the presence of (sun?) light will split the water into hydrogen and oxygen. Is this practical (for demonstration purposes) and are any other materials/apparatus needed? I cannot seem to find much useful information which answers this question elsewhere.

Comment: Your source did not mention oxygen gas?

Comment: The [reference in your source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4339798/) states that "$\ce{ZnS}$ is one of the most widely investigated photocatalysts because it rapidly generates electron-hole pairs under photoexcitation, and exhibits a relatively high activity for $\ce{H2}$ production under UV light."

Comment: It further links to [this site](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nl202587b) which contained the set-up.

Comment: @user34388, why don't you sum up your comments and write the answer to the question?